# MySQL query TRUNCATE ERROR

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i have query like this and dont know why it gives me the error. I want to create the table if it is not already created, if it is created, then truncate it and then insert into that that table the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
`(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`
(
    onlineId VARCHAR(255),
    paramId INT,
    paramValue INT
)
TRUNCATE TABLE
`(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`
INSERT INTO
`(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`
SELECT
`ui`.`onlineId`, `uin`.`paramId`, `uin`.`paramValue`
FROM
`(temp)v5_userInfo_COLD` `ui`
JOIN
`v5_(readOnly)userInfo_number` `uin`
ON
`uin`.`userId` = `ui`.`id`
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first two statements are missing delimiter **";"**
add them and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors in this. First, as @krishKM says, you have missing semicolons. The statements should be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`
(
    onlineId VARCHAR(255),
    paramId INT,
    paramValue INT
);
TRUNCATE TABLE  `(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`;
INSERT INTO `(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`
SELECT `ui`.`onlineId`, 
       `uin`.`paramId`, 
       `uin`.`paramValue`
FROM  `(temp)v5_userInfo_COLD` `ui`
JOIN `v5_(readOnly)userInfo_number` `uin` ON `uin`.`userId` = `ui`.`id`;
```

second, verify the privileges for the user that will execute this statements. `TRUNCATE` [requires DROP privilege since MySQL 5.1.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html)

My guess is that your user has DATA + CREATE privileges, but they are not enough.

If adding drop privileges is a showstopper, one possible workaround would be to execute

```
 DELETE FROM `(temp)_v5_userInfo_Netsprint_Data_import`;
```

Which is, of course, slower.

Comment: There problem was in missing semicolons. Thank you all for your helped, i have managed to solve the issue.